# Firebase Instrument test time out

Tags: ui-testing, android-instrumentation, firebase-test-lab

I ran the instrumentation test locally and everything is fine.
But It is always failed which times out when I connect to Firebase Test Lab. I have tried a few different devices but still no luck. Most of them just stuck in there and fail for a half hour.

[image: timeout]

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 665 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: package.name.dev:id/emailSignButton'.

at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at package.name.Utils$Companion.login(Utils.kt:42)
at package.name.views.active.SomeActivityTest.testPrebidAuction(SomeActivityTest.java:62)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2145)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Error loading RS jni library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/package.name.dev.test-Fa1GKc9fQmFQRxv4qGFwHg==/lib/arm64/librsjni.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit Support lib API: 2301
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.internalCreate(RenderScript.java:1414)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1599)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1549)
at android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1525)
at at.favre.lib.dali.builder.ContextWrapper.getRenderScript(ContextWrapper.java:36)
at at.favre.lib.dali.builder.blur.BlurBuilder.<init>(BlurBuilder.java:72)
at at.favre.lib.dali.Dali.load(Dali.java:123)
at package.name.ui.BackgroundImageFragment.onCreateView(BackgroundImageFragment.kt:44)
```

Answer (score 0):

How long do your tests take to run?  You may need to set a longer test timeout than the default timeout value in FTL, particularly if you use any virtual devices, which do not have a GPU to speed up graphic operations.

You can set the test timeout using advanced options from the Firebase Console, or by using the `--timeout` flag if you're using `gcloud` from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, I did set the longer time out. The thing is it just hang in there for a half-hour.